# Removing chrome webNavigation event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I remove a chrome.webNavigation event?

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(x.bind(request.data.url), {
    url:[{urlPrefix:request.data.url+""}]
});
```

This is how i am creating the event, and this is how i am attempting to remove the event inside the "x" function,

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(arguments.callee);
```

But oddly it's not removing the listener, instead every time addlistener is called I keep adding more and more listeners without removing the last one.

EDIT:
So it seems it's not possible to remove the anonymous function created by the .bind() function.

Comment: I just tried something similar with `window.addEventListener()`, it fails the same way.

Comment: note: with `addEventListener` in chrome(55) (also in firefox(50) and opera(42), but not in safari (yet), edge, or ie), there is an easier way to get a "one shot" event listener ... `window.addEventListener('whatever', fn, { once: true})` - as for the `.onCompleted.addListener` - there's a fairly simple way to overcome this issue (I think, will add answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a new [*bound function*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects) which calls the function you are binding, setting the appropriate `this` and adjusting the arguments to what you have specified, plus any which are used when the bound function is called.

You can get an idea for how this works from the [polyfill for `.bind()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).

Here is some example code that demonstrates that the `arguments.callee` is not the bound function:

```js
function toBeBound(arg1) {
    console.log('arguments.callee:', arguments.callee);
    console.log('arguments.callee === arg1:', arguments.callee === arg1);
    console.log('arg1:', arg1);
}
var bound = toBeBound.bind(null);
bound(bound);
```

The bound function that [you create with `x.bind(request.data.url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is a different function which calls `x()`. It is *not* `x`. Thus, when you are in the `x` function and try to:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(arguments.callee);
```

What you have effectively done is:

```js
    chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(x);
```

because, `x` is the `arguments.callee` at that time, having been called by the function created by `.bind()`. However, the function which you added as a listener was the *bound function*.

#### You need a reference to the *bound function* to remove the listener

The way to accomplish what you desire is to have a reference to the bound function, which you can use inside `x()` to remove the listener. One, simple, way to do that would be to add your listener like:

```js
var boundX = x.bind(request.data.url);
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(boundX, {
    url:[{urlPrefix:request.data.url+""}]
});
```

Then, in your `x()` function, you can remove the listener using:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(boundX);
```

Obviously, how you implement this may need to be more complex for your actual code. However, given the minimal amount of code you have provided, anything more complex would just be speculation on my part. In some situations, I've kept Arrays or Objects containing the references to the bound functions I've used as listeners.

#### Only calling the listener once

If your use case is that you *always* want to remove the event listener the first time that the event fires, then Jaromanda X has provided a good solution to accomplishing that in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814485/3773011). It's basically an ES6 based implementation of the the standard way to build a generic method to call an event listener once (prior to `addEventListener` having the ability to [specify `once` as an option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)). What it does is creates a function to automatically hold the reference to the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this with addListener/removeListener, only with addEventListener/removeEventListener - however I think the logic is sound

```
function once(ev, filter, listener) {
    const fn = (...args) => {
        listener(...args);
        ev.removeListener(fn);
    }
    ev.addListener(fn, filter);
}
```

and, the usage in your case would be

```
once(chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted, {url:[{urlPrefix:request.data.url+""}]}, x.bind(request.data.url));
```